# SilverLight XAML. Binding цвета эллипса к элементу массива цветов

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

У меня есть эллипс, и вот такая конструкция:

```
private Brush lampColor;
public Brush LampColorTest
{
    get { return lampColor; }
    set
    {
        lampColor = value;
        OnPropertyChange("LampColorTest");
    }
}
```

С помощью какой-то команды я задаю LampColorTest значение, допустим, Yellow. Когда это происходит, эллипс перекрашивается в желтый цвет. Привязываю эллипс я так:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Path=LampColorTest}"
```

МНе нужно сделать так же, но чтобы LampColorTest был массивом цветов и каждому эллипсу привязывалась соответствующая ячейка массива цветов, например, так:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Path=LampColorTest[1]}"
```

Как этот сделать? Заранее очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: хм, интересный вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написать свой [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx)?

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int index;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out index)) 
    {
        // грязно ругаемся
    }

    var list = value as IList;
    if (list == null || list.Count < index + 1)
    {
        // аналогично
    }

    return list[index];
}
```

Comment: а дальше как это будет выглядеть? Не понимаю немного, приведите пожалуйста пример кода как это применить()конвертировать и как в XAML коде это записать?

Comment: Там же по ссылке выше есть пример.
Какому-нибудь родителю в ресурсы добавляем:

    <Grid.Resources>
       <local:ListFormatter x:Key="ListFormatter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

Затем используем в Binding (ConverterParameter - это индекс массива):

    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Path=LampColorTest, Converter={StaticResource ListFormatter}, ConverterParameter=1}">

Comment: А как быть с ConvertBack если требуется?